# How to persist the selection of a favourite from a SwiftUI List?

Tags: swiftui

I am following along with this SwiftUI Tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

The concepts here are perfect for an app I want to create. I do however have one question.

Whilst this tutorial is great for showing the basics of using Environment Objects to update SwiftUI views (in this case, to add a star image to elements that have been favourited.), how might I go about saving these changes to last beyond the app's runtime.

Right now, I can favourite a bunch of Landmarks but if I quit and re-launch the app, those selections are lost. Is there a "SwiftUI friendly" way to store those favourite selections and have the main Landmark List view automatically draw the star images to mark previously chosen favourites when the app is launched cold? I'm guessing UserDefaults would be the way, but I don't know how well that will adapt to these funky Environment Objects.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I am now using UserDefaults to persist an array of "TeamProfile" objects which gets appended to whenever a team is marked as Favourite.

In my SwiftUI code, I am trying to add Star images to favourites with the following code. These TeamRow items are built into a List by the parent view.:

```
struct TeamRow: View {
    var team: TeamProfile

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(team.TeamName)
            Spacer()

            if team.isFavourite || teamsSelected.contains(team) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .imageScale(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

teamsSelected is the array that is being maintained by UserDefaults. It *should* add a star to TeamRow items from my persisted array (which is loaded on app launch and I can verify it's contents). However, the star is only drawn on the row if I make *new* favourite selections during the app session.

I can verify the contents of the data I am persisting with UserDefaults, so I don't know why SwiftUI is not responding by starring the correct elements when the app is launched.

Comment: normally you should provide your tryout code here...yes, you can e.g. save the data in e.g. set {} to userdefaults and read it in get {} from userdefaults. or u can save it in coredata or in a file...there is no SwiftUI way to do it because as it says "UI" has nothing to do with storing informations, but with displaying ;)

Comment: EnvironmentObject is just a class, ordinary class (all publishing things just run-time add-ons), so encoding/decoding, storing/restoring, ie. its persistency, is absolutely out of SwiftUI care. It is up to you: UserDefaults, CoreData, file, cloud - where you want to keep your model... is only your dreams limit.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have made changes to include UserDefaults, but I cannot get SwiftUI to draw UI elements by checking what this array contains when the app is launched.